# JPA @Entity Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpa, persistence

I have been looking into JPA/Hibernate `@Entity` inheritance for a while now and can't seem to find anything that addresses what I am trying to achieve.

Basically I want to be able to define an `@Entity` with all of the column and table mappings as required. Then I want to be able to extend the `@Entity` in a number of different locations with different sets of `@Transient` methods defined in the body of each "sub-Entity". This is a basic example of what I am trying to achieve but with no success thus far:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mountain")
public class MountainEntityBase implements Serializable {
    public Integer mountainId = 0;
    public Integer height = 0;

    public List<ExplorerEntityBase> explorers = new ArrayList<ExplorerEntityBase>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "mountain_id")
    public Integer getMountainId() { return mountainId; }
    public void setMountainId(Integer mountainId) { this.mountainId = mountainId; }

    @Column(name="height")
    public String getHeight() { return height; }
    public void setHeight(String height) { this.height = height; }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mountainId")
    public List<ExplorerEntityBase> getExplorers() { return this.explorers; }
    public void setExplorers(List<ExplorerEntityBase> explorers) { this.explorers = explorers; }

}
```

.

```
@Entity
public class MountainEntity extends MountainEntityBase implements Serializable {

    public List<MountainEntity> allMountainsExploredBy = new ArrayList<MountainEntity>();

    @Transient
    public List<MountianEntity> getAllMountainsExploredBy(String explorerName){
        // Implementation 
    }
}
```

So any extended class will define only `@Transient`s in its body. But also I want to allow for situations where the child class is empty:

```
@Entity
public class MountainEntity extends MountainEntityBase implements Serializable {
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. In JPA, only fields are serialized, not methods. Only fields can be declared transcient: this keyword has no effect on methods.

Comment: Hi Benoit thanks for your reply and sorry for the confusion :P I have tried to clarify my original post. So basically it is the inheritance aspect of the entity that I want to get sorted before I get the actual transients implemented. So even if the child class is empty I can't seem to use it. I keep getting entity not mapped errors. Thanks again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inheritance in JPA is specified on the root entity using the `@Inheritance` annotation. There you can specify the database representation of the hierarchy. Check [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html) for more details.

If your child classes define only transient fields (not methods) (i.e. not saved in the db), then perhaps a discriminator column is the best option. But it may be the case that you don't actually need inheritance - the main entity can have all the methods (because it has all the fields the methods operate on)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am more interested in the inheritance aspect than the use of transients at the first pass. Basically I want to also cater for situations where the child class is also empty. (See original post [edited]). Is it possible to do this using the inheritance annotation? Thanks again

Comment: yes, it is possible. You will just have to specify a discriminator value. I linked the documentation - it's a must-read ;)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without adding a new column to every table in the database?

Comment: I don't think you should have many tables for inheritance that doesn't add any fields. It can be all in one table (with an additional discriminator column)

Comment: Yeh I was hoping to avoid having to add a new column into every table whose entity I want to extend. You see I want my entities to be clear of any dependencies outside of other entities so that I can move them as a JAR into other modules of my site in the cloud. So I am trying to find a solution that allows me to have Base entities that I can extend in any external modules with only code specific to that module. I doesn't seem as though JPA provides non-polymorphic entity extension. Is that accurate to your knowledge?

Comment: hibernate needs to have a criteria based on which to instantiate one subclass or another. If there is no discriminator field, hibernate cannot know which of many subclasses you want (or even - do you want to base class or the child)