# Java Persistence and entity classes

Tags: java, sql, jpa, ibatis

I have two entity classes - `A` and `B`. The template of the code is as follows:

```
class A extends class B  {
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table("OPERATION")
@DiscriminatorValue()
@Access()
class B  {
    // ...
}
```

Class `B` has a schema defination in the .sql file. Class `A` does not have any schema defination.

My question is, doesn't class `A` need to have a schema definition in the .sql file as well, in order for it to be mapped to the relational database? I am confused on this and cannot understand how the mapping is taking place.

To use a more concrete example, I have the following two classes `Operation` and `OperationAmend` with their code as follows :

```
 @Entity
 @DiscriminatorValue()
 @Access()
 class OperationAmend extends Operation {   
     //some functions here for amending an operation
 }

 @Entity
 @Table("OPERATION")
 @DiscriminatorValue()
 @Access()
 class Operation  {   
     //some functions here for the operation.
 }
```

SQL Schema :

```
 CREATE TABLE OPERATION {    
     OperationId INT;    
     Name VARCHAR(20); 
 }
```

How can the `OperationAmend` class be saved even when it has no schema?

Comment: Related: [JPA @Entity Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6170564/1065197)

Comment: I use ibatis and inheritance mapping in ibatis is a bit different..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JPA, an entity only has to be declared in the persistence.xml (or scanned for by the provider) for it to be recognized.  The provider generates a schema for it.  Now, the implementation tables might not exist in the DB, but that's easy enough to fix.